Is it possible to record all network traffic when using playwright codegen?
Is it possible to record all network traffic when using playwright codegen?
Record all network requests and responses on pages during codegen.
and replay the testcase using the recorded network traffic.
playwright doc read, but not found solution

You don't need codegen to do this, just regular Playwright. Codegen is for generating selectors--why do you want to use it instead of normal Playwright code for monitoring traffic? What are you trying to achieve?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Codegen is to generate locators.
My suggestion: Run the entire test script. Open the playwright report and check the traces. You can see the network requests and responses recorded there.
